# How to activate test-unit for RubyMine when developing a library (gem)?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubymine, testunit

I'm developing a library (a gem) using Ruby 1.9.2. My Gemspec looks like the usual for a gem:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

# Specify your gem's dependencies in table_builder.gemspec
gemspec
```

while in my gemspec I have this line:

```
s.add_development_dependency "test-unit"
```

I can see it's being installed and my Gemfile.lock includes it:

```
PATH
  remote: .
  specs:
    foobar (0.0.1)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    test-unit (2.4.5)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  foobar!
  test-unit
```

In my Rakefile I load it with:

```
require "rubygems"
require "test/unit"
```

as well as in my test_helper.rb:

```
require "rubygems"
require "test/unit"
```

In the command line the tests run and pass, but in RubyMine, whether I run tests or the test rake task, I get this message:

> MiniTest framework was detected. It is a limited version of original
>   Test::Unit framework. RubyMine/IDEA Ruby plugin test runner requires
>   full-featured version of the framework, otherwise default console
>   tests reporter will be used instead. Please install 'test-unit' gem
>   and activate it on runtime.

I'm using RVM, so I checked the SDK is the one I'm using on the command line and test-unit is listed in the list of installed gems.

So, how I activate test-unit in a way that RubyMine likes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RubyMine 4.0 (in RC2 at the time of this writing) supports minitest and managed to run the tests out of the box. Way to go JetBrains!

Answer (score 1):

Please [refer to help](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/ruby-gems-support.html). You need Gemfile with the used gems listed in it for RubyMine to recognize the dependencies.

Comment: That would go against the common practice for gems, which is to list the dependencies in the gemspec and in the Gemfile just point to the gemspec. Are you sure RubyMine doesn't understand that?

Comment: Make sure that "Run this script in context of the bundle" option is enabled in the Run/Debug configuration, Bundler tab.